# Expanding 3 lists using placeholder

Tags: scala, functional-programming, currying

Section 9.3 of Programming in Scala by Martin Odersky shows an example of using placeholder _ to reference the "second" function in a curried function

[image]

[image]

Say I have 3 lists instead:

```
def curriedSum(x:Int)(y:Int)(z:Int) = x+y+z
```

which I can write thus

```
def f(x:Int) = ((y:Int) => ((z:Int) => x+y+z))
```

and access the intermediaries like so

```
def f(x:Int) = ((y:Int) => ((z:Int) => x+y+z))
                                                  //> f: (x#582190: Int#1111)Int#1111 => (Int#1111 => Int#1111)
        val b = f(1)                      //> b  : Int#1111 => (Int#1111 => Int#1111) = <function1>
        val c = b(2)                      //> c  : Int#1111 => Int#1111 = <function1>
        c(3)                              //> res0: Int#1111 = 6
```

But how can I access the intermediaries (b and c in the above code) with placeholders á la the case of 2 lists? The best I could do was

```
  def k = curriedSum(1)_                          //> k: => Int#1111 => (Int#1111 => Int#1111)
  k(2)(3)                                         //> res1: Int#1111 = 6
```

which isn't very satisfying at all since I've skipped an intermediary. How can I bring back the "third" function with placeholders?

Here is the fictitious pseudocode for what i'd like to achieve.

```
k = curriedSum(1)__
l = k(2)_
l(3)
```

Comment: why you have two underscores for k in your fictitious psedudocode, typo?

Comment: those were meant to be placeholders for the second and third parameters respectively.

Answer (score 1):

There are three approaches I can think of:

```
def k = curriedSum(1)_                    //> k: => Int => (Int => Int)

def l = k(2)(_)                           //> l: => Int => Int
l(3)                                      //> res0: Int = 6

def m = k(2)                              //> m: => Int => Int
m(3)                                      //> res1: Int = 6

def n = k.apply(2)                        //> n: => Int => Int
n(3)                                      //> res2: Int = 6
```

An interesting thing to understand the difference between multiple parameter lists and one parameter list.

```
def l = curriedSum(1)(_: Int)(_: Int)           //> l: => (Int, Int) => Int
l(2,3)                                    //> res0: Int = 6
//l(2)(3) ERROR

def m = curriedSum(1)_                          //> m: => Int => (Int => Int)
//m(2,3)  ERROR
m(2)(3)                                   //> res1: Int = 6
```

Comment: I'm not sure I get the difference between putting parentheses around the _ and not putting any parentheses. If anything ```curriedSum(1)(_:Int)(_:Int)``` looks like a multiple parameter list, 3 parameters to be exact because it follows the pattern ```f(x:Int)(y:Int)(z:Int)```. Also, why in ```k(2)(_)``` we could get away with not specifying the parameter type, whereas in ```curriedSum(1)(_:Int)(_:Int)``` we had to specify type?

Comment: Doesn't ```_``` just mean "the rest of the parameters", regardless of how many there are? So why the asymmetry between ```_ ```representing 2 "rest of parameters" and having to use```(_)``` to represent 1 "rest of parameters" when we have 3 parameters? Even more puzzling, when we have only two parameters, we now use ```_``` to represent 1 "rest of parameters" instead of ```(_)``` like we did for the 3 parameter case!

Answer (score 0):

You can still do this, with slightly different syntax:

```
scala> def l = k(2)(_)
l: Int => Int

scala> l(3)
res3: Int = 6
```